# How to display a "busy" indicator with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I display a spinning "busy" indicator at a specific point in a web page?

I want to start/stop the indicator when an Ajax request commences/completes.

Is it really just a matter of showing/hiding an animated gif, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can just show / hide a gif, but you can also embed that to ajaxSetup, so it's called on every ajax request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(){
        // show gif here, eg:
        $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete:function(){
        // hide gif here, eg:
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

One note is that if you want to do an specific ajax request without having the loading spinner, you can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
   global: false,
   // stuff
});
```

That way the previous $.ajaxSetup we did will not affect the request with `global: false`.

More details available at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup

Comment: +1 for `ajaxSetup()`. Would prefer if further explanation about the `global` property was given.

Comment: @RabidFire, actually global is not needed here, it's just for $.ajax

Comment: @gov, positioning the gif depends of the layout, you can just hide / show the div where it's placed, instead of modifying dom.

Comment: This looked promising but it didn't work for me, ended up trying a different solution that worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003707/getting-jquery-beforesend-and-complete-to-work-in-rails-3

Comment: If you have 2 XHRs, and the first one finishes right after the second one starts, this code hides the loading indicator even though the second XHR is still running.

Comment: Warning! This answer is outdated. As noted in the [jQuery.ajaxSetup API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) you should now use the global Ajax event handler methods: `.ajaxStart()`, `.ajaxStop()`, etc...

Comment: amazing and awesome solutions.

Answer (score 41):

The jQuery documentation recommends doing something like the following:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).hide();
});
```

Where `#loading` is the element with your busy indicator in it.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/
- In addition, [`jQuery.ajaxSetup` API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) explicitly recommends avoiding `jQuery.ajaxSetup` for these:

  > Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods—`.ajaxStart()`, `.ajaxStop()`, `.ajaxComplete()`, `.ajaxError()`, `.ajaxSuccess()`, `.ajaxSend()`—rather than within the `options` object for `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Comment: These seem more useful than beforeSend and complete, because ajaxStart will "...Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins" and ajaxStop will "...Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed" - these handle concurrent async messages and wont hide the "please wait" indicator prematurely.

Answer (score 10):

I tend to just show/hide a IMG as other have stated. I found a good website which generates "loading gifs"

[Link](http://www.ajaxload.info/)
I just put it inside a `div` and hide by default `display: none;` (css) then when you call the function show the image, once its complete hide it again.

Answer (score 6):

yes, it's really just a matter of showing/hiding an animated gif.

Comment: Agreed. Show/hide an image is easy and understood by all browsers. There are a couple jquery rotate plugins for images but those won't work in all browsers.

Comment: @mike my solution is working fine for my project in all browsers, do you think that is nice approach

Answer (score 5):

I did it in my project ,

make a div with back ground url as gif , which is nothing but animation gif

```
<div class="busyindicatorClass"> </div>

.busyindicatorClass
{
background-url///give animation here
}
```

in your ajax call , add this class to the div and in ajax success remove the class.

it will do the trick thatsit.

let me know if you need antthing else , i can give you more details

in the ajax success remove the class

```
success: function(data) {
    remove class using jquery
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend Rodrigo's solution a little - for requests that are executed frequently, you may only want to display the loading image if the request takes more than a minimum time interval, otherwise the image will be continually popping up and quickly disappearing

```
var loading = false;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Display loading icon if AJAX call takes >1 second
        loading = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (loading) {
                // show loading image
            }
        }, 1000);            
    },
    complete: function () {
        loading = false;
        // hide loading image
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it in my project:

Global Events
in application.js:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

"loading" is the element to show and hide!

References:
http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 3):

I had to use

```
HTML:
   <img id="loading" src="~/Images/spinner.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />

In script file:
  // invoked when sending ajax request
  $(document).ajaxSend(function () {
      $("#loading").show();
  });

  // invoked when sending ajax completed
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
      $("#loading").hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but i wanted to update since i worked on this problem today,
i didnt have jquery in my project so i did it the plain old javascript way, i also needed to block the content on the screen so 
 in my xhtml

```
    <img id="loading" src="#{request.contextPath}/images/spinner.gif" style="display: none;"/>
```

in my javascript

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').style.opacity = '0.7'
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the plain old javascript way"? Could you explain further? Do you mean you used an `XMLHttpRequest`?