# Getting JQuery beforeSend and complete to work in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement the solution as outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355268/how-to-display-a-busy-indicator-with-jquery) but can't get it to work.

```
application.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend:function(){
          $('#loading').show();
        },
      complete:function(){
          $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});

application.html.erb

  <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="/img/ajax-loader-circle.gif" ></br></br>Please wait...</div>
```

From my form, I added `:remote => true` and I could tell that an AJAX call was made looking at Rails logs. However, `beforeSend show` never got triggered. Thoughts?

Comment: `</br></br>` should be `<br/><br/>`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using:

```
$('#loading').ajaxStart(function(){
  $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

or if you want it for a particular form ID:

```
$('#someFormID')
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```

Make sure it's wrapped in a DOM ready block (like you've done).  These are both working examples from one of my apps.