# "Please wait, loading" alert on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client, alert

I have a button- when it is clicked, an alert shows up, prompting for an input, after the user puts in data, the data is sent to the server, processed, and a result comes out. This can last up to 30 seconds-1 min, because I have to handle quite a large amount of data, so I would need to show a "Loading, please wait" alert, while the server-side job is running, so the user won't think things are not working.

Can anyone offer any suggestions, please?
I am quite new to javascript and jquery. I have a feeling this has to be done with ajax, but I don't really know how.

Comment: We have no idea what you're using here. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: As I said, I am new to javascript and Jquery, and I've been searching for a while for something useful- but I didn't really find anything until now

Answer (score 1):

I think the same question has been asked here - [How to display a "busy" indicator with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355268/how-to-display-a-busy-indicator-with-jquery) and a verified answer with code is provided.

Comment: Is there any way to set things up individually rather then setting them globally and individually removing?
And will this also affect ajax calls from other files than the one with ajaxSetup?

Comment: If your scenario is in some cases of invoking one ajax request to have indicator and in othere cases when invoking it to dont have i would advise you before doing the request to set the indicator and to use promisses - when. Please take a look at - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

What you need exactly a Jquery Plugin Named Block UI 
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Source code and working demo can be found at

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#page

As per comment if you want to do it for indivisual ajax
you can unblock in success or error handler of Ajax call... suppose

```
$.ajax({
     url: "test.html", 
     cache: false, 
     beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } });
     }
}).done(function( html ) {
     // Do your work 
     $.unblockUI();
 });
```

Comment: looks nicely, but how will I know when to unblock if I don't want to block all ajax requests?

Comment: you can unblock in success or error handler of Ajax call... suppose `.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  // Do your work 
// Unblock
});`