# Busy Indicator while page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I want to display a busy indicator when the page is loading html.

I tried to put a `jquery` dialog but it doesn't work because the page is loading.

I'm using `jquery`, `bootstrap` and `html5`.

Comment: You really should try to Google this **before** you post a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a "busy" indicator with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355268/how-to-display-a-busy-indicator-with-jquery)

Comment: @sebaMelgar: En Inglés, por favor. *(In English, please.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

Display a loading-gif on your page:

```
<div class="loading">
    <img src="path/to/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

And then hide it when the page is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.loading').hide();
});
```

or hide it when some ajax-calls are completed:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
     $('.loading').hide();
});
```